# Gatsby failing production build

Tags: gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

Recently, Gatsby started failing to build a production version of the site. Development version builds fine.

It seems to be some Babel issue but I can't figure out what it is. I've upgraded everything, deleted the node_modules folder and yarn.lock but after building everything afresh again it fails the same way.

I'm not particularly familiar with the inner workings Babel so I'm guessing this is something to do with the Babel settings shipped with Gatsby?

```
 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome/index.es.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome/index.es.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@mikaelkristiansson/domready/ready.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/@mikaelkristiansson/domready/ready.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@reach/router/es/index.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/@reach/router/es/index.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@reach/router/es/lib/utils.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/@reach/router/es/lib/utils.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby-link/index.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/gatsby-link/index.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby-react-router-scroll/index.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/gatsby-react-router-scroll/index.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/lodash/lodash.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/mitt/dist/mitt.es.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/mitt/dist/mitt.es.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/netlify-identity-widget/build/netlify-identity.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/netlify-identity-widget/build/netlify-identity.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/prop-types/index.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/prop-types/index.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/react-add-to-calendar/dist/react-add-to-calendar.min.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/react-add-to-calendar/dist/react-add-to-calendar.min.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/react-dom/index.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/react-dom/index.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/react-helmet/lib/Helmet.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/react-helmet/lib/Helmet.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/react-image-gallery/build/image-gallery.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/react-image-gallery/build/image-gallery.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/react-share/es/index.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/react-share/es/index.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/react/index.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/react/index.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/shallow-compare/es/index.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

File: node_modules/shallow-compare/es/index.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")
    at validateTopLevelOptions (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/normalize-options.js:49:13)
    at normalizeOptions (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/normalize-options.js:160:3)
    at _default (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:168:37)
    at /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:19:12
    at loadDescriptor (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:165:14)
    at cachedFunction (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:33:19)
    at loadPresetDescriptor (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:235:63)
    at config.presets.reduce (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:77:21)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at recurseDescriptors (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:74:38)
    at recurseDescriptors (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:94:27)
    at loadFullConfig (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:108:6)
    at process.nextTick (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:28:33)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

File: src/components/share.scss


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")
    at validateTopLevelOptions (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/normalize-options.js:49:13)
    at normalizeOptions (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/normalize-options.js:160:3)
    at _default (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:168:37)
    at /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:19:12
    at loadDescriptor (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:165:14)
    at cachedFunction (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:33:19)
    at loadPresetDescriptor (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:235:63)
    at config.presets.reduce (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:77:21)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at recurseDescriptors (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:74:38)
    at recurseDescriptors (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:94:27)
    at loadFullConfig (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:108:6)
    at process.nextTick (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:28:33)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

File: node_modules/react-add-to-calendar/dist/react-add-to-calendar.css


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")
    at validateTopLevelOptions (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/normalize-options.js:49:13)
    at normalizeOptions (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/normalize-options.js:160:3)
    at _default (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:168:37)
    at /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:19:12
    at loadDescriptor (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:165:14)
    at cachedFunction (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:33:19)
    at loadPresetDescriptor (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:235:63)
    at config.presets.reduce (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:77:21)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at recurseDescriptors (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:74:38)
    at recurseDescriptors (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:94:27)
    at loadFullConfig (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:108:6)
    at process.nextTick (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:28:33)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

File: node_modules/react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")
    at validateTopLevelOptions (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/normalize-options.js:49:13)
    at normalizeOptions (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/normalize-options.js:160:3)
    at _default (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:168:37)
    at /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:19:12
    at loadDescriptor (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:165:14)
    at cachedFunction (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:33:19)
    at loadPresetDescriptor (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:235:63)
    at config.presets.reduce (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:77:21)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at recurseDescriptors (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:74:38)
    at recurseDescriptors (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:94:27)
    at loadFullConfig (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:108:6)
    at process.nextTick (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:28:33)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

File: src/templates/gallery.css


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")
    at validateTopLevelOptions (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/normalize-options.js:49:13)
    at normalizeOptions (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/normalize-options.js:160:3)
    at _default (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:168:37)
    at /Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:19:12
    at loadDescriptor (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:165:14)
    at cachedFunction (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:33:19)
    at loadPresetDescriptor (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:235:63)
    at config.presets.reduce (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:77:21)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at recurseDescriptors (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:74:38)
    at recurseDescriptors (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:94:27)
    at loadFullConfig (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:108:6)
    at process.nextTick (/Users/carlosbeneto/Documents/JS/lonely-lentil-site/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:28:33)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Here's my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.19",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
"bulma": "^0.7.5",
"core-js": "2",
"gatsby": "^2.13.31",
"gatsby-image": "^2.2.6",
"gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^2.1.4",
"gatsby-plugin-netlify": "^2.1.3",
"gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms": "^4.1.6",
"gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms-paths": "^1.2.2",
"gatsby-plugin-purgecss": "^3.1.1",
"gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.2",
"gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.1.3",
"gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.2.8",
"gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.2.3",
"gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files": "^2.1.3",
"gatsby-remark-images": "^3.1.6",
"gatsby-remark-relative-images": "^0.2.2",
"gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.5",
"gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.6.7",
"gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.2.4",
"lodash": "^4.17.15",
"lodash-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.4",
"netlify-cms-app": "^2.9.6",
"node-sass": "^4.12.0",
"parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3",
"prop-types": "^15.6.0",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-add-to-calendar": "^0.1.5",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-facebook": "^7.0.6",
"react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
"react-image-gallery": "^0.8.18",
"react-share": "^2.4.0",
"uuid": "^3.2.1"
```

},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can help for local builds, but I had the same issue when deploying on Netlify today and I have been able to solve the issue by switching to npm.

Here is the steps I followed:

- removed `yarn.lock` and old `package-lock.json`
- added `yarn.lock`, removed `package-lock.json` from `.gitignore`
- removed `node_modules` folder
- re-installed dependencies with npm
- run build command with npm

Comment: That seems to have done it! I'm intrigued as to way though, shouldn't npm and yarn work the same?

Comment: Didn't work for me, should I also remove `.cache`? I removed it but it didn't fix anything

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but I had the same issue as this and realized I had a `package-lock.json` and a `yarn.lock` file. I deleted my `yarn.lock` file and it fixed the error.

Comment: I've tried that to not avail, it's really driving me mad as I cannot pinpoint what's causing this. I've tried different versions of everything!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This saved me so much time.